# Django production sever extremely slow upload images

Tags: python-3.x, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

i have created an application in python Django where users can upload some images.
MY application as localhost development work perfect and very faster.

Now i want to to run as production using Nginx and gunicorn server and port forward for education reasons.
My problem is if i run as productions my site has extremely slow in upload images.
I don't know why is wrong and i have such a big difference on time upload,is my first time as production .

is the some application development and production and i think the problem is some setting in NGINX server or GUNICORN server.

I use Ubuntu jammy and not some linux server.

here the settings :

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
     listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/username/PycharmProjects/myproject/static/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/username/PycharmProjects/myproject/myproject_app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/PycharmProjects/myproject/myproject.sock;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    # Add the proxy headers hash size settings
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

    server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name localhost;

        # Add the client max body size setting
        client_max_body_size 100M;

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/username/PycharmProjects/myproject/static/;
        }

        location /media/ {
            alias /home/username/PycharmProjects/myproject/myproject_app/media/;
        }
    }

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=saran
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/PycharmProjects/myproject
ExecStart=/home/username/.local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 10 --bind unix:/home/username/PycharmProjects/myproject/myproject.sock --worker-class gevent myproject.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

sudo nginx -t:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

sudo systemctl status nginx.service:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-03-30 13:07:46 EEST; 1h 1min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 11109 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_proc>
    Process: 11110 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (>
   Main PID: 11111 (nginx)
      Tasks: 33 (limit: 37329)
     Memory: 26.3M
        CPU: 1.756s
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─11111 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; maste>
             ├─11112 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11113 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11114 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11115 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11116 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11117 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11118 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11119 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11120 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11121 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
             ├─11122 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "
```

sudo journalctl -xeu nginx.service:

```
Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nginx.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit nginx.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3828.
..............................................................
```

sudo systemctl status gunicorn

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-03-30 13:08:08 EEST; 1h 8min ago
   Main PID: 11246 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 11 (limit: 37329)
     Memory: 1.5G
        CPU: 23.344s
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
..................................
```

i try to read documentation of nginx and gunicorn and to change sever settings.
I expecting to find solution for the slowly upload images and i would like to some time if i work development server.